# c# Streaming data to SQL Server, handle connection error

Tags: c#, sql-server, streaming

**Problem:**
There is a huge blob that is streamed from a server to a client application.
If there is an exception (connection lost), while writing the stream to the database, all so far received data is lost and the database field remains empty afterwards.

**Question:** Is there a way to change that behavior, so that the database holds all so far received data and just stores it, even if there is an exception? I want to resume the download later.

**Important note:** I don't want to buffer the whole received data in memory, I just want to directly write the received data to the database, to avoid memory peaks. I'm using HttpClient with HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead in order to achieve that. If there is no connection issue, everything works as expected.

**Workaround so far:** I can write the received data in temporary file first, and then after a connection issue, I just store what I received to the database. That will work, but is there a better approach?

**How the stream is written currently:**

```html
 string connectionString = "connection String";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
conn.Open();

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update TableX set Data=@data where id = @id")) {
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ParameterDirection.Input);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", streamToStore);
 cmd.Connection = conn;

 int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```

Comment: How are you currently writing the stream to the DB?

Comment: just updated the question with some sourcecode. Just using basic .net sql classes.